# Using "a" with the word "slang"

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, uncountable-nouns

Can I use the word "slang" with an indefinite article "a"?
For example:

> That phrase is an obvious slang.

or

> That choice of words is an obvious slang.

Comment: This usage seems particularly common with *German* non-native Anglophones (who are also likely to refer to ***a software*** when they mean ***a piece of software / an application***). See the Family Guy skit mocking "non-idiomatic" use of the article in ["Lois made **a porn**"](https://familyguy.fandom.com/wiki/And_I%27m_Joyce_Kinney/Quotes).

Comment: Note that *as a noun*, the word ***slang*** refers *collectively* to *all* colloquial / cant usages, NOT to a single instance of a slang usage. In the cited context, you must either discard the article *(That usage is slang)* or use the term *adjectivally* to modify a context-suitable noun *(That usage is **a** slang **expression / term / word / ...**)*

Comment: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/slang?q=slang

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not just Germans do that. Other Germanic language speakers (like Dutch and Scandinavian languages) do that. People from India do it a lot too. "A software" is bad enough, but to my programmers ears "A code" is even more cringe-worthy.

Comment: @Tonny: You're quite right - I should have said *Germanic* languages. I don't know how many Far Eastern languages fall into the "opposite" camp, but *on average*, speakers of "non-Romance" Northern European languages tend to overuse articles in English, whereas speakers of Far Eastern languages usually *underuse* our articles (perhaps because their language doesn't really use articles, so the concept is harder to grasp).

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is my experience too. Seems that unconsciously many people use more or less the same article structure from their native tongue into whatever language they try to speak.

Comment: @Tonny: Perfectly understandable. I don't know, but I wouldn't mind betting that many *Indian* languages naturally favour the equivalent of English continuous participles, which is what leads them to inappropriate usages such as *I am loving my wife very much*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"Slang" as a noun refers to the entire body of very informal language and terms, not just one word. So, we would say "*it is a slang word*", **not** "it is a slang". That would be like saying "It is an English" instead of "it is an English word" - English being the entire body of spoken language. As there are many slang words, the indefinite article is appropriate in this construction.

The alternative without an article would be to say that the word is part of slang, for example, "the word is obvious slang".

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes, when you're talking about a slang language.

"Slang" as a noun refers to the entire body of informal words, idioms, and phrases that occur within a group. As such, "a slang" refers to the entire body of such a linguistic grouping.

For instance, you could say "Strine is a slang primarily spoken by rural White Australians".

Comment: In other words, "no", for the two examples that the OP gives.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Sure, but this is the answer to the actual question they asked.

Comment: Strine is Australian English, an English dialect spoken by Australians. I'm not sure it's correct to classify it as just slang (note the absence of the indefinite article).